# latch warning due to case statement with codeword from ps2 keyboard verilog

Tags: verilog

Im working with ps2 keyboard and a basys2 to simulate the behavior 
of two elevator in a building of 4 floors (sub, 1, 2 and 3)

This code saves the internal requirements of each elevator, cw is the codeword from the ps2 keyboard

The paremeters defined are the codewords for the keys (ps2 keyboard keys) used in the simulation 
[ps2 keyboard codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mUUm.png)

```
module reg_in2(
    input [7:0] cw,
    output reg[3:0] reqin_a1,
    output reg[3:0] reqin_a2
    );
parameter a1_sub =  8'h6b;
parameter a1_1 = 8'h6c;
parameter a1_2  = 8'h75;
parameter a1_3 = 8'h7d;
parameter a2_sub = 8'h70 ;
parameter a2_1 = 8'h69 ;
parameter a2_2 = 8'h72 ;
parameter a2_3 = 8'h7A ;

initial
begin
reqin_a1 = 4'b0;
reqin_a2 = 4'b0;
end

always@(cw)
begin
    case(cw)
    a1_sub: reqin_a1[0] = 1;
    a1_1: reqin_a1[1] = 1;
    a1_2: reqin_a1[2] = 1;
    a1_3: reqin_a1[3] = 1;
    a2_sub: reqin_a2[0] = 1; 
    a2_1: reqin_a2[1] = 1;
    a2_2: reqin_a2[2] = 1;
    a2_3: reqin_a2[3] = 1;
    default: begin
                reqin_a1 = reqin_a1;
                reqin_a2 = reqin_a2;
                end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

The only warnings i get are  (for every bit of reqin_a1 and reqin_a2)

```
Found 1-bit latch for signal <reqin_a1_0>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.

The value init of the FF/Latch 0 hinder the constant cleaning in the block reqin_a1_3.
   You should achieve better results by setting this init to 1.

Gated clock. Clock net
   req_in1/reqin_a2_1_cmp_eq0000 is sourced by a combinatorial pin. This is not
   good design practice. Use the CE pin to control the loading of data into the
   flip-flop.
```

My problem is not an error but an unexpected behavior of Basys2, i'm using the LED's to check reqin_a1 and reqin_a2 values.
When i press some of the designed keys in the ps2 keyboard, more than one led lights on. 
Example: I press 2 in ps2 keyboard (parameter a2_2) and reqin_a2[0] and reqin_a2[2] are changed to 1
I've really tried a lot of things, so i would really appreciate some help

Comment: I guess you have some glitches on the `cw` signal which cause the behavior. Could be caused by your input method or some electrical properties of fpga. Usually all designs like that are floped to avoid such issues. So, create `clock`, flop and link the model clock to the fpga clock.

Comment: and, btw, you set values to '1', but never clean them. you need to provide a way to turn them to '0' as well.

Comment: I actually found a patch solution, using a debouncer (or rather a lock) to stop listening other keys . I'm short of time now so i'll skip your advice, thanks anyway. 
(This is test code, only involves setting the reqs to 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Level-sensitive latches occur when a `reg` is defined in no-sequential always block and is not assigned to a determinate value for all possible branches. For example `always @* if (en) q = d;` is an latch because `q` is not assigned a value when `en` is low. Adding `else q = q;` will still infer a latch.

The reason multiple lights turn on on a button press is the enable logic is not clean. The bits of `cw` maybe arriving a few nanoseconds/ picoseconds apart. There is also the prorogation delay matching `cw` to each state. In both case are likely culprits for a glitch.

The easiest solution is to make the design synchronous by adding a clock.

```
always @(posedge clock)
begin
    case(cw)
    a1_sub: reqin_a1[0] <= 1;
    a1_1: reqin_a1[1] <= 1;
    // ...
    a2_2: reqin_a2[2] <= 1;
    a2_3: reqin_a2[3] <= 1;
    // Note default is not required
    endcase
end
```

When intentionally creating a latch, keep the enabling logic clean. Preferably from a clock source. And use non-blocking assignment `<=`. Try to keep the latching logic as simple as possible. I recommended having a separate always block for each latch-enable signal. Latch are often unintentional. Make it easy for anyone reading your code and the synthesizer to identify intentional latch. Use comments (human only), pragmas (tool specific), or enable SystemVerilog and use `always_latch` (universal).

Comment: Indeed, the warnings disappeared. But now it's not working at all, i press a key and nothing happens. I tried with a reduced frequency clock.(frequencys from 1Mhz to 50kHz)

Comment: Reducing the clock frequency would lower the sampling rate. 1MHz is every 1us, while 50kHz is every 20us. Both should be enough for a key press assuming that `cw` retains the same value while held down. You need to make sure `cw` has the value you wait on the left-hand-side of `reg_in2`'s rising clock. If you run in Verilog simulation instead of FPGA, you can debug the behavior in waveform.  There is not much more I can help without seeing seeing how your code determines `cw` from the ps2 protocol.

Comment: I finally solved it. Verilog was somehow ignoring my assignments (i guess because i always assigned an 1). When I integrated my final solution, which eliminated the requirements that were no longer valid, it worked.

Comment: Ah. It wasn't Verilog. It was your synthesizer that decided to "optimize" it to 1. Adding a reset condition would resolve it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, is there any place to learn about it?

Comment: Im sure there must be some documentation on synthesis gotcha somewhere. I learned it by sitting next to and becoming friends with engineers that been doing logic design before Verilog got an IEEE number.